# Browser based file upload to AWS S3 and encode server-client workflow

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, client-server, communication

Im writing a single-page-web-app (angularJs) and a server back-end (node.js). The communication between them is done via REST.

Currently im trying to implement the following scenario:

1. Upload big files from browser to S3 public bucket.
2. Copy uploaded file to private bucket on S3
3. Transcode uploaded file to HTML 5 compatible format (AWS Elastic Transcoder)
4. Store Meta-Object about the file in DB to access later

I'm racking my brains to get a well working design of the communication/ data-workflow between server and client, but always got stuck at the following questions?

- Store file meta-object at the end or at the beginning of the process. If it is at the beginning, i have to store and handle some state information?
- Who should start copying uploaded files to private bucket. Server or client? If it is the server, how can the client get informed about the job succeeded?
- Who starts the transcoding process? If it is the server, how can the client get informed about the job succeeded?

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

there is a pretty good tutorial which describes the use case you are planning to implement: http://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/02/create-mpeg-dash-hls-content-for-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

If your transcoding system has a RESTfull API (like bitcodin which is used in this tutorial, or any other service) you can do your application also client-side and use the API calls to get the state of your transcodings, etc. However, using the API you can do the same also server-side, whatever fits better for you.

I personally would store the metadata infos at the beginning of the process, as this is the point of time where you generate the "asset" in your database/CMS/etc.

Comment: Thx for your answer Stefan. I checked out the tutorial you linked and indeed this fits what I plan to implement. Main difference is, that all of this steps should be done automatically,  in my system. The user is just dropping the file into the browser. That's the point where data and communication flow between server and client starts being not that obvious to me. How can the client get informed about the transcoding has finished if server starts this process?